# Streaming audio on the Raspberry Pi Zero W with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, pi-zero, alsa, ffmpeg

I have a problem with ffmpeg giving no audio when recording using alsa.

Does anyone know how to get a Raspberry Pi Zero W to record and stream audio with ffmpeg using alsa?

I have a project where I am using I2S digital microphones hooked up to an Raspberry Pi Zero W. The microphones are [from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3421), and I set them up using [this guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test). I have two microphones set up in stereo mode. Now, when I use

```
arecord -D plughw:1 -c2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V stereo -v file_stereo.wav
```

everything works great. I can copy the file over to my main machine and it plays fine. Now, when I try something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -re -i hw:1,0 -acodec mp2 -ac 2 -f rtp rtp://[host]:[port]
```

and try playback via either VLC or ffplay, I only get silence and/or clicking sounds. ffplay indicates that a connection is being made, so it isn't a network issue. I have also verified that the input device is in fact the correct one. I have attempted just replicating arecord through ffmpeg with

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 -t 10 out.wav
```

However, this does the same as piping it through RTP. I have tried different codecs: mp2, mp3, aac. I even tried different input and output sampling rates, channels, etc. Nothing works. I have used the ffmpeg available in the Stretch repositories and compiled it myself where I knew it had the alsa library enabled.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried `-ac 2 -ar 48000` input options instead of `-re` - in the documentation for `-re` it says **Should not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams**

Comment: Brodi, did you ever figure out a solution for this? I have the same setup and am also getting empty recordings when trying to use `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I ended up finding this forum post which contains some working examples of piping arecord to ffmpeg, which is the best option I've been able to find so far: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=173809